# Write over data in a file without closing it and opening it back up. (c++)

Tags: c++, for-loop, file-io

I want to open a file, read the data, and after a calculation, write over the data that I read, but I don't want to close it and re-open it, because this will slow down my program as it does this over and over again and it does slow it down.
Essentially, I have a starting number, then I do some calculations and move on to the next number. Since I don't want to redo all these calculations, I have a file with the starting number in it and a file with the output list. I want to change the starting number so I'm not needlessly redoing calculations. If you need to see some of my code, just say so. Thanks guys/gals/variations thereof.
I'm using c++.

Comment: Why do you need to write the file each time vs doing it all in memory, and write it when you are done?

Comment: @HanletEscaño Because I have it going on an infinite loop and i stop it whenever I shut down my computer or something.

Comment: If you really want to position write at the beginning of a file look up ostream::seekp() in your favorite book or FAQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I have reached the end of the file, the eof flag will be set. I need to clear that using (ifile is the fstream variable in this example) `ifile.clear` – then try seeking:

```
ifile.clear();
ifile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if you have the contents on memory, but anyway you can use seekp to change the pointer to the actual position in file

Comment: I use a file so I can continue where I left off after I closed the program.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are trying to achieve can be done using fstream the syntax is very similar to this:

```
std::fstream file;
file.open ("textfile.txt", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
```

Here is a link to a better explanation http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/